# Single function iterate a map or slice with generics

Tags: go

Is there a way using Go's new generics to have a single `for` in a function be able to iterate over a loop or a slice?

This is roughly what I'm wanting to do, with a little more logic attached based on keys.

```golang
func iterateContent[K []interface{} | map[string]interface{}](items K) {
    for k, _ := range items {
        fmt.Println(k)
    }
}
```

This code though gives me the following error

> cannot range over items (variable of type K constrained by []interface{}|map[string]interface{}) (K has no core type)

---

There are other questions on StackOverflow about how to iterate varying types of slices, but they're fundamentally different than varying between a slice and a map.

Comment: @Gavin Their solution doesn't apply. They're trying to iterate two different types of slices, I'm trying to iterate a map or a slice. Some of what's said here though kind of implies what I'm trying to do might not be possible, but I'd love the chance to be proven wrong.

Comment: But it does answer this question, @donatJ. Unless you can name, "a single type U which is the underlying type of all types in the type set of T".

Comment: The expression to the right of `range` keyword [must](https://go.dev/ref/spec#RangeClause) have a [core type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Core_types). Type constraint `K` is: it is either a slice or a map. There is no type in Go that satisfies `K`. In other words the compiler tells you - it has no iterators that suite both slices and maps. May be in the future they introduce `Iterable` interface, but there is none as for now.